# How to initiate a setInterval function with 0 sec but repeat it for a given time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I'm currently using a `setInterval` function so that I can repeat text with an extra letter added to it for every 5 secs, hence I've set the time period for the `setInterval` function as 5000.

But I also want this function to be executed as soon as the page loads. To be clear the logic present inside the `setInterval` function should be executed as soon as the page loads and it should also be repeated for every 5 secs. Is it possible with `setInterval` function or else is there any other way to do it? Thank you in advance :)

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var x = document.getElementById('sample');
  x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML+'L';
  },5000);
```

```html
<p id="sample">Sample Text</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it a separate function, which you can then call right away. On top of that, you'll then have some nice reusable code:

```js
function updateElement(){
    var x = document.getElementById('sample');
    x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML+'L';
}

setInterval(updateElement, 5000);

updateElement();
```

```html
<p id="sample">Sample Text</p>
```

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a try

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Logic is so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use named function run on init and call it each interval

```js
setInterval(function someFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById('sample');
  x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML + 'L';
  return someFunc
}(), 1000);
```

```html
<div id="sample"></div>
```